# Want to put all words at the site with the color blue and uppercase

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla

I'm building one site at JOOMLA and at this site i want to put all the word "Inovflow" on the site, at the color blue and upercase. Like this "INOVFLOW".

I put this code on the js folder of the site:

```
jQuery(document).fn.findText = function(params){
    var phrases = params.query, 
        ignorance = params.ignorecase;
        wrapper = $(this);
    var source = wrapper.html();
    selection_class_name = params.style;
    source = source.replace(/[\n|\t]+/gi, '');
    source = source.replace(/\s+/gi, ' ');
    source = source.replace(/> /gi, '>');
    source = source.replace(/(\w)</gi, function(m, w){return(w + " <");});

    phrases.forEach(function(str){

      var regexp = makeRegexp(str);
        source = source.replace(regexp, function (m){
          return (emulateSelection(m));
        });

    });

    wrapper.html(source);
    var res_array = wrapper.find("[search=xxxxx]") 
    return(res_array);
};



function makeRegexp(s){
  var space = '( )?(<span[^>]*>)?(</span[^>]*>)?( )?';
    var result = s.replace(/\s/gi, space);
    result = new RegExp(space + result + space, "gi");
    return(result);
}

function emulateSelection (htmlPiece){
  htmlPiece = htmlPiece.replace(/(?!=>)[^><]+(?=<)/g, function(w){
    return(wrapWords(w));}
  );
  htmlPiece = htmlPiece.replace(/^[^><]+/, function(w){
    return(wrapWords(w));}
  );  
  htmlPiece = htmlPiece.replace(/[^><]+$/, function(w){
    return(wrapWords(w));}
  );
  htmlPiece = htmlPiece.replace(/^[^><]+$/, function(w){
    return(wrapWords(w));}
  );

  return( htmlPiece );
}

function wrapWords(plainPiece){
  console.log("plain: " + plainPiece);
  var start = '<span search="xxxxx">',
    stop = '</span>';
  return(start + plainPiece + stop);
}


jQuery(document).each($('.container').findText({query: ['INOVFLOW']}), function (){
    $(this).addClass("changeColorInovflow");
});
```

After this, the page seems to get on a Infinite loop and doesn't load. 
if instead of `jQuery(document)` I use `$.` the JS returns a error and doesn't run.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you add an example of the markup you're attempting to modify?

Comment: @twernt what do you need? I might be able to give you more details

Comment: @RicardoAlves with a "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's much more likely that someone will be able to answer the question.

Comment: @twernt my problem is that outside of JOOMLA this code works. I tried it on a snippet and it worked, passed it to JOOMLA and didn't ran (at that time I had $. instead of jQuery(document). Now with jQuery(document) it just gets on a infinite loop. I've edited the question with this info.

Answer (score 0):

If `findText` is intended to be a jQuery plugin, you'll need to update the way the function is declared.

```
$.fn.findText = function(params) {
  var phrases = params.query;
  // removed unused 'ignorance' var
  var wrapper = this; // this is already a jQuery object
  var source = wrapper.html();

  selection_class_name = params.style;
  source = source.replace(/[\n|\t]+/gi, '');
  source = source.replace(/\s+/gi, ' ');
  source = source.replace(/> /gi, '>');
  source = source.replace(/(\w)</gi, function(m, w){return(w + " <");});

  phrases.forEach(function(str){
    var regexp = makeRegexp(str);
    source = source.replace(regexp, function (m){
      return (emulateSelection(m));
    });
  });

  wrapper.html(source);
  var res_array = wrapper.find("[search=xxxxx]") 
  return this; // return 'this' to make it chainable
}
```

Here are the relevant docs:

https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Then, when you call `findText`, you can use a much simpler selector:

```
$('.container').each(function() {
    $(this).findText({query: ['INOVFLOW']}).addClass("changeColorInovflow");
});
```

The original code wouldn't work because `each()` takes either a function or an array with a callback as parameters, not a selector.

`.each()`: http://api.jquery.com/each/

`jQuery.each()`: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: You'll probably also want to use a class on the updated text to make it easier to style and, if there are multiple `.container` elements, modify the `findText` call. Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/twernt/cc4uy75w/.